Zero Force and Infinite Acceleration when Mass is zero
My text says "If the net external force on a body is zero, its acceleration is zero. Acceleration can be non zero only if a net external force acts on the body". But this compels me to think of the case where the mass approaches 0 (body is assumed massless). Then by F = ma, F approaches  0 however, acceleration would approach infinity. How?

I am not an expert at this field, but remember when velocity becomes comparable to light speed or mass become so small (smaller than Planck Mass), Newtonian Mechanics will fail and must be replaced by relativity or quantum mechanics.

I think the better equation for force is $F = \frac{dp}{dt}$ and as you approach higher speeds classical mechanics stops being relevant and you're stepping into relativity. relativistic speeds you replace momentum with four-momentum and speed with proper time: $F = \frac{dP}{d\tau}$. Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-force

The short answer is that Newtonian Mechanics assumes all bodies have a non-zero mass. A vanishing mass, at constant values of the forces, would imply increasing acceleration and the possibility that the system would get velocities such that a relativistic treatment would be in order.
Still, there are cases of classical systems where a better understanding of the limit $m\rightarrow 0$ is useful. However, one should consider that such a limit, in the case of the equation of motion $F=ma$ with a fixed force, is highly non-trivial. From the mathematical point of view, it corresponds to a problem in the class of singular perturbations.
From the physical point of view, the vanishing of the mass implies an increasing separation of the scales of time of the motion of the small mass from those of the other dynamical variables. Special techniques have been developed to deal with such situations (average methods, adiabatic approximations, etc.).

For a given net force $F$ that has a set value, yes, as $m\to0$ we have $a\to\infty$. There is no issue with this. Limits never reach the actual value of question; they only explain what things approach. This should make sense though... the smaller the mass, the larger its acceleration from a net force.
Similarly, for a set acceleration $a$, $F\to 0$ when $m\to 0$. This makes sense because as the mass gets smaller you need to apply a smaller force to maintain the same acceleration.
The case you have described of both $m\to 0$ and $a\to\infty$ without a force specification is undetermined, since you have to specify how each variable approaches those "values"; $F$ doesn't necessarily approach $0$ (or even $\infty$) in that case. In other words, $m\to0$ and $a\to\infty$ will occur no matter what $F$ actually is.

thanks :), got it. approaching 0 times approaching infinity would be indeterminate

Yes, in the case of vanishing mass,, the net force has to approach zero at at any acceleration.
